# Bluebeam pdf file conversion

Tags: c#

I have created c-sharp application in which bluebeam software is used to convert doc files to pdf files. Bluebeam Q manager is running in one of the machine with in the network.

I connect to the bluebeam servicce using below code.

```
ITask task = TaskManager.CreateNewTask();

IInputFile[] inputFile = { task.InputFiles.Add(sourceFile[j]) };
taskController = task.GetController("servername where bluebeam service is running");
```

Which connects to the Bluebeam Q. I have added input files by browsing from my local drives.

```
IInputFile[] inputFile = { task.InputFiles.Add(sourceFile[j]) };
```

For example say D:\Test.doc.. which need to converted to the pdf using Bluebeam Q.

But the problem i am facing is Bluebeam Q manager checks the input file which i passed in its own local directory and returns the error.
I tried giving the path in the following way as well,

```
\\ipaddressof my machine\D$\inputfilename
```

But it doesn't seems like working. As thousands of users will use the app, i cannot write the file in to server also. Any suggesions?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why cant it be written to the server? Pass it along, have a small monitoring app watch for its arrival, watch for the creation of the PDF when its made then it deletes the passed in file and pushes the PDF back. This is the process we use with our PDF creation, i realise this isnt what you asked for exactly which is why its a comment. Thought it might help your situation to know what we do though

Comment: I have done something like that. When browse the input files write them to the server shared folder and convert them to pdf in server itself and then copy to the local folder. But i am afraid whether it is a wrong process as the number of clients will be more.

Comment: Even if it is on your local machiene though its going to have to read across all those bytes at some point, even if it is just 'in memory' the method we have then says if there is an issue, then instead of deleting the file move it to the issues folder and attach the log to it so we have a copy of the problem file and a log, easy to reproduce errors,

Comment: not neccesarily through choice but because like yours, the third party software refuses to read across a network, so we just did what we had to to make it work, plus this way if there is a network issue mid PDF transform that means it cant access the local machien it wont cause as many issues, as its local, it can continue its job from just whats local, and go on its way until the network is back up